# How to not update database if $_POST value is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, database, forms

I have been having problems with a form of an website of mine. The form values are equal to their corresponding $_POST values, which are the parameters used for updating the database.

I do not want for empty form values to be updated. However, I don't want any of the input areas to be obligatory.

That means that I would be able to update only specific content, not needing to type the values in the input areas I do not want to update. I'm having problems with this, however. Empty form values are being uploaded, so the values in the database are being changed into blank values. I've looked for tutorials in SO and over the internet, and the only (functional) ones are those which turn input boxes into obligatory. That is not how I intend it to work, so it doesn't fit.

I think the best way to do this, and I am not sure, is to change, through javaScript, the "name" attribute of the input areas into blank when the submit button is set IF the values equal empty or null. I do not know how to do this, nor do I know if this is possible, or the best way.

Here is my current code on the matter:

(first, the form an the javascript)

```
<script>
function validade(){
    var formId = document.getElementById("configForm");
    var allInputs =  formId.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var input, i;

    for (i=0; input = allInputs[i]; i++){
        if (input.value == null || input.value == "") {
            input.name = "";
        }
    }
}
```

```
<form method="post" action="" id="configForm">
<label for="home">Home:</label>
<br>
<input type="text"  id="home" name="home">
<br>
<label for="apendix">Apêndice:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="apendix">
<br>
<label for="about">Sobre:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="sobre">
<br>
<label for="contato">Contato:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="contato">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Carregar" name="submit">
</form>

<?php require_once('editaForma.php'); ?>
```

(Secondly, the database query and $_POST values:)

```
<?php //credentials
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $server = 'hypotetical';
    $user = 'hypotetical';
    $pw = 'hypotetical';
    $BD = 'hypotetical';

    //estabelece a conexão
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $BD);
    if (!$conn) {
        die ('<span style="color: #FF0000;">"connection failed: "</span>' .  mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $home = $_POST["home"];
    $apendix = $_POST["apendix"];
    $sobre = $_POST["sobre"];
    $contato = $_POST ["contato"];

    $query = "UPDATE form SET 
    home= '$home',
    apendix= '$apendix',
    sobre= '$sobre',
    contato= '$contato'
    WHERE id='1'";



    //$query = "INSERT INTO form (home, apendix, sobre, contato) VALUES ('$home', '$apendix', '$sobre', '$contato')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
        echo "Alterações feitas com sucesso";
    } else {
        echo "ERRO!" . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn); 
}
?>
```

Yes, I know the DB is prone to SQL injection. I'm trying to get everything up and running first, and once all of this is set, I'll look onto security matters before the website is online.

I've been having this problem for over a week and can't figure a way out of it.

Thank you for your time and attention, in advance.

**EDIT**

I wish I could select two answers for the solving ones. Both of them right down led me to the solving of the problem, each helping me to see the holes in my code. As I cannot choose both, I chose the one who helped me to solve the last issues. Thank you all so much!

Comment: You have the answer in your title already: `if`: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php And since you're already using that elsewhere in your script, what is the mental block keeping you from using it to make the `query()` call conditional?

Comment: Stop making excuses about "trying to get it working" and start using prepared statements. They fix more problems than they create, you'll never have escaping issues that take hours to track down if you use them in a disciplined fashion. In this case it's literally two more lines of code and it can save a world of hurt should this code inadvertently go into production, which code tends to do when you're not looking.

Comment: sorry if it sounds stupid. I'm learning code in a sort of chaotic fashion. Will put more effort into it, then, and learn prepared statements. Thank you.

Comment: As an alternate option, just pre-fill the form with the current values from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your query dynamically, by skipping empty values

```
$p = &$_POST; //make $p refer to $_POST

$query = "UPDATE from SET ";

if($p['home'])    $query .= " home = '$p[home]' ,";
if($p['apendix']) $query .= " apendix = '$p[apendix]' ,";
if($p['sobre'])   $query .= " sobre = '$p[sobre]' ,";
if($p['contato']) $query .= " concato = '$p[contato]' ,";

$query = trim($query, ','); //remove any trailing comma 
$query = "WHERE id = 1";
```

you can then execute the query.  Oh and don't forget to check that at least 1 of the variables was available. If they're all empty, don't execute.

And yeah, your code is highly vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you. This did it. The thing is, I don't get why $p['home'] doesn't update blank values, whereas $home would. Would you care to explain?

Comment: let me see if I got this right, the trim() function removes empty space, so the, say, $p[home], if empty, does not get computed. Is that right?

Comment: @PauloSoares the trim in the above code just removes the trailing comma, as the comment suggests.  There is no space trimming swapping going on.  If $p['home'] is an empty string it evaluates to false and that part of the query is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Glaring security holes aside, I would usually build up a string, something like this:

```
$home = $_POST["home"];
$apendix = $_POST["apendix"];
$sobre = $_POST["sobre"];
$contato = $_POST ["contato"];

$query = "UPDATE form SET ";
if(!empty($home)) {
    $query .= "home= '$home',";
}
if(!empty($apendix)) {
    $query .= "apendix= '$apendix',";
}
if(!empty($sobre)) {
    $query .= "sobre= '$sobre',";
}
if(!empty($contato)) {
    $query .= "contato= '$contato',";
}

// strip off any extra commas on the end
$query = rtrim($query, ',');

$query .= "WHERE id='1'";
```

Building the query with the comma at the end also allows you to easily add more options later if you need to.

Comment: This is pretty much a clone of http://stackoverflow.com/a/39111266/3392762

Comment: The posts were made at about the same time, and when the posts were originally posted the accepted answer didn't include the `trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, in a simple way using NULLIF

```
set potato = NULLIF(potato,'')
```